# Loop through json object and display the data with React?

Tags: json, reactjs, loops, state

The api response i get back has 10 objects of people inside it and i would like react to display the Persons name and gender. I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Is states even the right way to go about this or should i try to save my response inside of an array only?

Any help is appreciated.

```
state = {
        Person: null,
        Gender: null      
}
    
async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "**********************************************";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({Person: data[0].Name})
    this.setState({Gender: data[0].Gender})

    }

render() {
    return  <div>
        <p>
        {this.state.Person}
        </p>

        <p>
        {this.state.Gender}
        </p>
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should store your data in state and map it to display the name and gender of each person.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "**********************************************";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data })

    }

render() {
    return(
        {this.state.data.map((el, id)=> 
        <div>
        <p>Name:{el.Name}</p>
        <p>Gender:{el.Gender}</p>
        </div>
        )}
)}
```

Comment: Please let me know if it solved your problem or not.

Comment: I'm fresh on React so im currently trying to implement this to my project. I'm getting this problem: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, I'm guessing im not doing it right.

Comment: I made it work, where can i read more about this? So that i actually understand whats going on behind the scenes? Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Well, in my opinion, the documentation of react is the best resource as they have written it very informative and simple. I also found videos of Mosh on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0) useful and simple when I started learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

Should definitely use an array of "Persons", also try using hooks :)